# can I use strtotime('now') as unique ID in PHP?

Tags: php

Can I use [strtotime("now")](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) as a unique ID in php application as I assume it uses current timestamp and cannot generate the same integer in future?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20363/shortest-way-to-generate-uuids-version-3-4-and-5-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not safe to use `strtotime('now')` as id

take a look at this code:

```
$now = strtotime('now');
$anotherNow = strtotime('now');
$sameCounter = 0;
while($anotherNow == $now){
    $sameCounter++;
    $anotherNow = strtotime('now');
}

echo $sameCounter; //8558
```

Result is **8558**, very not safe, php did 8558 operations during that second
There's big chance that you'll get the same ID few times.

you can use `uniq` function instead

Answer (score 3):

Uniq id is itself a php function , you can have this like this

```
$uniq = uniqid();
```

you can add more entropy in this

Answer (score 2):

My be rare chance  we can get duplicates ,  you can prefix username 
Like this echo "$username-".time(); or "$username".time(); or "$userid-".time();

In php already have `uniqid` .

> The uniqid() function generates a unique ID based on the microtime
>   (current time in microseconds).

For  more information please refer official website http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Answer (score 1):

I'm using for small projects, like as mini blog or cms.
this function generate 10 digits with unix time 
and change every second, if your project not biq and not get high request or inserts you can use this safely.

```
$UniqID = time();
```

it create ID with 10 digits like (1462570078)

for other project I use microtime more than time() or other uniq like this

```
$m=microtime(true);
echo sprintf("%8x%05x\n",floor($m),($m-floor($m))*10000);
```

Comment: What is two PHP requests doing it exactly same time? it's seconds and not milliseconds, too much unsafe

Comment: in mini project I use this, and in question not define project is big or small but you are right

Comment: the Question is, "is it safe to use `time` as id", you just said that you are using `time` and not explain why it is safe \ unsafe

Answer (score 1):

No, don't do that. Although the timestamp is likely to always be different that doesn't mean it's unique. For instance, what would happen if two requests are issued at the same time? You will have two equal timestamp. When choosing unique IDs, you have to be sure that there's no possible cases in which there are equals values. A good solution is having an auto-increment field. That will make sure that your id will never be the same.